# What is the differential of the adjoint action of a Lie group, $\partial_t{\rm Ad}(\gamma(t))V(t)$?

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Given a Lie group $G$ with Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$, the adjoint action $Ad:G \rightarrow GL(\mathfrak{g})$ is given as the differential of the conjugation map in the unit element.

Given two curves $\gamma: I \rightarrow G$ and $V:I \rightarrow \mathfrak{g}$.

> What is $\frac{d}{dt} Ad (\gamma(t)) V(t)$?

I think the answer should be $$\frac{d}{dt} Ad (\gamma(t)) V(t) = ad \left( dL_{\gamma(t)^{-1}}\gamma'(t) \right) V(t)+Ad(\gamma(t))V'(t),$$ but I am not sure.

$Ad$ is a special case of a map $f:M \times N \rightarrow P$ from a product manifold into some other manifold.
For $(m,n) \in M \times N$ and $V \in T_mM$, $W \in T_nN$ we have (remember $T(M\times N) \simeq TM \times TN$):
$$
df_{(m,n)}(V,W)
=
df_{(m,n)}(V,0)+df_{(m,n)}(0,W)
\\
=
d\left( f \mid_{M \times \{n\}} \right)(W,0)+d\left( f \mid_{\{m\} \times N} \right)(0,W).
$$

In the case of $Ad$:
$$\frac{d}{dt} Ad (\gamma(t)) V(t)
\\
=
d Ad_{(\gamma(t),V(t))} (\gamma \times V)'(t)
\\
=
d Ad_{(\gamma(t),V(t))} (\gamma \times const)'(t)
+
d Ad_{(\gamma(t),V(t))} (const \times V)'(t)
\\
=
\frac{d}{ds} \mid_{s=t} Ad (\gamma (s)) V(t)
+
\frac{d}{ds} \mid_{s=t} Ad (\gamma (t)) V(s)
\\
=
\frac{d}{ds} \mid_{s=t} Ad (\gamma (s)) V(t)
+
Ad (\gamma(t))V'(t).
$$
But why is $\frac{d}{ds} \mid_{s=t} Ad (\gamma (s)) V(t)=ad (dL_{\gamma^{-1}(t)} \gamma'(t)) V(t)$? 
Or is this the case anyway?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suspected answer was wrong.
The correct formulae are
$$
\frac{d}{ds}
\mid_{s=t}
Ad(\gamma(s)) V(t)
=
Ad(\gamma(t)) ad(dL_{\gamma^{-1}(t)} \gamma'(t)) V(t)
$$
and
$$
\frac{d}{dt}
Ad(\gamma(t))(V(t))
=
Ad(\gamma(t)) ad(dL_{\gamma^{-1}(t)} \gamma'(t)) V(t)
+
Ad(\gamma(t))V'(t)
$$
respectively.
The second line follows from the first as mentioned in my initial post.
To prove the first line:

$\frac{d}{ds}
\mid_{s=t}
Ad(\gamma(s)) V(t)$

$=\frac{d}{ds}
\mid_{s=t}
dL_{\gamma(s)}dR_{\gamma^{-1}(s)} V(t)$

$=\frac{d}{ds}
\mid_{s=t}
dL_{\gamma(t)} dR_{\gamma^{-1}(t)} dL_{\gamma^{-1}(t)\gamma(s)} dR_{\gamma^{-1}(s) \gamma(t)} V(t)$

$=\frac{d}{ds}
\mid_{s=t}
dL_{\gamma(t)} dR_{\gamma^{-1}(t)} Ad (L_{\gamma^{-1}(t)} \gamma(s)) V(t)$

$=Ad(\gamma(t)) ad(dL_{\gamma^{-1}(t)} \gamma'(t)) V(t)$.